# How to make a variable store permanently, so it does not restart to original when I click run - python

Tags: python

So I have the problem, I want to count numbers in python. I want it so that if I ask a question the user gets 10 points but if I click run it restarts the points back to 0 becuase the variable is equal to zero. Is there a way to store the points permanently so that when I run again the points are still there.

I am a noob so I don't know what to try
also I just started learning python so i don't know much so can you explain it to me in simple terms as i just started learning and understand nothing

Comment: You need to store it in a file then

Comment: sorry what did you say

Comment: Save it to a file, I said

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do that or what that does i am a complete noob

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at how to read and write text files in python

```
#get score in your program and then do this
score = 10
def saveScore(x):
    file = open("myfile.txt","a")
    file.write(str(x)+'\n')
    file.close()
def readScore():
    file = open("myfile.txt","r")
    return file.readlines()[-1]

#save score everytime time it changes
saveScore(score)
#this function will score of last saved state
score = readScore()
```

Comment: That is a good example, but data can be stored in *binary* files as well. Maybe mention pickle, DBs, etc

Comment: Yeah but as he mentioned he has just started python that why I didn't think it was a good idea :)

Comment: can someone explain each part of the code because i am a noob

Comment: got through this link once https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-file-handling